# Is it possible to run Hive queries on HDFS without using YARN?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, hadoop-yarn

I've used Hive and Hadoop in pseudo distributed mode configuration ***with YARN** and my queries ran correctly and gave the expected results.*
Now for my project, I have to run the same Hive query in pseudo-distributed mode **without YARN** and in **local mode**.

To run Hadoop in pseudo distributed mode without YARN I've only removed the properties in files: ***etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml***   and   ***etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml*** , but when I'm going to create my tables in HDFS there is always the same problem where it seems he can't find any reducer:

```
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2020-12-17 18:35:02,251 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2020-12-17 18:35:14,304 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_local1317984459_0001
Stage-4 is selected by condition resolver.
Stage-3 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Stage-5 is filtered out by condition resolver.
  [......]
 Time taken to load dynamic partitions: 16.956 seconds
     Time taken for adding to write entity : 0.016 seconds
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 2201663 HDFS Write: 2327026 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
OK
Time taken: 56.534 seconds
```

When I'm going to run my query, instead, there is this error:

```
Total jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Defaulting to jobconf value of: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2020-12-17 19:39:34,746 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_local1837749065_0002 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://localhost:8080/
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

How can I run my Hive query in pseudo distributed **without YARN** and in **local** mode?

Comment: I dont know the reason behind this, but this can happen if you're loading many partitions. Hive, especially beeline has this pathetic way of telling that something is wrong. Can you tell me how much is the data?

Comment: I have something like 215 partitions, and the original csv file I use to load information in the table weights about 3 MB.

Comment: The main problem,I think, is that Hive uses no reducer when I disable YARN on HDFS (he actually does lots of mapping phases (due to the partitions) but no reduce phases).

Comment: I think mapping and reducing depends on the query. If in the final load, you're creating 215 partitions, then most likely it will fail. There is probably default limit of 100. I dont remember exact configuration property. Check how many partitions it was bound to create. Also can you confirm if it's beeline or hive?

Comment: All this is quite strange because I made another attempt:
I create the initial table from my CSV file without partitions, then I run my simple query in Hive:   

_SET hive.exec.mode.local.auto=false;  
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=314570;    
set mapred.job.queue.name=long_running; 
SELECT data, sum(NVL(ipat,0)) + sum(NVL(hospat,0)) as somma 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY data 
ORDER BY somma desc LIMIT 5;_

Comment: First time it runs correctly, but if I run *the same query* for the second time I have exactly the same error of the initial question above

Comment: Check Job Tracking URL and find exception in the failed attempt logs